# Executing .vbs from PowerShell script does not work but running the .vbs from PowerShell command line does

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am trying to write a PowerShell script which will be eventually used as a test automation for certain hardware which uses a network switch to toggle power to a remote system.

The network switch can be accessed by local telnet port interface.

My PowerShell script implementation looks as follows:

`test.ps1`:

```bsh
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\<path_to_file>\off.vbs";

Start-Sleep -s 10; # wait 10 seconds so that hardware powers down completely
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\<path_to_file>\on.vbs";
```

`off.vbs`:

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /C"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ("telnet 172.28.104.32{Enter}")
WshShell.SendKeys ("pset 4 0{Enter}")
WshShell.SendKeys ("logout{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WScript.Quit
```

`on.vbs`:

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /C"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ("telnet 172.28.104.32{Enter}")
WshShell.SendKeys ("pset 4 1{Enter}")
WshShell.SendKeys ("logout{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WScript.Quit
```

If I run this in a PowerShell console the operation works:

[image: powershell cmd line]

However, if I run the PowerShell script I do not see any operations.

Edit: the controlling machine on this PC is a vanilla windows 10 box and no new software can be used like putty or plink , there is a constraint to using inbuilt windows executable + some scripts (Security Reasons)

Comment: Changing cscript.exe to wscript.exe apparently works. but not sure why as both are almost identical.

Comment: `cmd /c` creates a shell that exits instantly without doing anything; you need `cmd /k` to keep it open. Generally, sending keys and using fixed sleep intervals is fragile. `cscript` runs a script synchronously as a console application, whereas `wscript` runs a script asynchronously as a GUI application.

Comment: Do not use `SendKeys()` for telnet automation.

Comment: Take VBScript out of the picture and just run telnet directly in powershell

Comment: we have a selected amount of software on this controlling machine and not really able to add putty/plink to this for implementation per security reason apply (which are sort of unfair) @AnsgarWiechers that linked solution does not apply here

Comment: adding 'cmd /k' works correctly. I do not have background in windows environment but that explanation was helpful :) . That would be the official solution for this problem with minimal change. i actually tried it with just 'cmd' and no options an that seemed to work as well.  I agree @mklement0 that this kind of scripting is not stable to run with guaranteed result but it is a quick fix until i can figure out a way to overhaul the design.

Comment: I mean no offense, but "we're using telnet" and "we can't use third party software because of security requirements" is a contradiction.  It's difficult to get *less secure* than telnet.  If these are your requirements, your project management process is broken.

Comment: i dont think its Security Persay its The IT Team that manages the deployment of these controller machines, idk they dont want to add an extra strep to the deployement of their windows 10 controller boxes beacause they would have to   run security regression on any new software introduced on this box. Since the both telnet devices are on a  secure local network i dont see why i should be prevented from using plink but i digress @BaconBits